i am not able to connect my physical android device(OS:13) with EC2 server
To connect my physical android device to my laptop and EC2 instance i am using appium and cmdlinetool.Locally with my laptop using usb i am able to connect my device and i veridied with "adb devices" command and it is showing connected device but same process i am doing on EC2 instance but here no devices are listed.
i am new on this process to connect physical device on my local laptop using USB and try to access it on EC2 server
i need help to setup this
i have setup cmdline-tool,platformtools,buildtool,tools,system-images all on my EC2 server and installed adb as well but physical device which is connected my local laptop using USB is not showing on EC2 instance
